# why fill in a matrix with a vector by matrix() is not working as expected?

Tags: r, matrix

[image]

As shown in the picture, it showed me "numeric 48" instead of actual numbers from the vector. Why is that and how to fix it? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The 'x' is a `data.frame`, so we may need to either convert to `matrix` with `as.matrix`

```
x1 <- as.matrix(x)
```

Or `unlist` the `data.frame` and convert to `matrix` with new dimensions

```
x1 <- matrix(unlist(x), 8, 6)
```

---

Reproducible example with

```
data(iris)
x1 <- matrix(iris, 150, 5)
head(x1)
#     [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]        [,5]       
#[1,] Numeric,150 Numeric,150 Numeric,150 Numeric,150 Numeric,150
#[2,] Numeric,150 Numeric,150 Numeric,150 Numeric,150 Numeric,150
#[3,] Numeric,150 Numeric,150 Numeric,150 Numeric,150 Numeric,150
#[4,] Numeric,150 Numeric,150 Numeric,150 Numeric,150 Numeric,150
#[5,] factor,150  factor,150  factor,150  factor,150  factor,150 
#[6,] Numeric,150 Numeric,150 Numeric,150 Numeric,150 Numeric,150
```